# How to let Firefox access system files?

Tags: permissions, firefox, snap, apparmor

I am trying to package an HTML user guide with my app.

Currently, it is placed in `/etc/oqm/static/guide.html`, with read permissions set to all.

However, firefox doesn't seem to have access to it.

I have checked `snap connections firefox`, and it seems like Firefox *should* have access:

```
Interface                 Plug                            Slot                             Notes
...
system-files              firefox:etc-firefox             :system-files                    -
...
```

After some more digging, I found [this post (mozilla support)](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1428538), which leads me to believe that it is in appArmor's realm. I tried some of the steps outlined there, but apparmor didn't seem to like it (I don't think I had the syntax correct).

I just noticed if I navigate using Firefox's `File`->`Open File...` menu option, I can in fact open the file, but it gets opened as `file:///run/user/1000/doc/ea9741/stationCaptainUserGuide.html`. This is close, but hard to make openable from a `.desktop` entry.

How can I let firefox access my guide? Are there any better places to put it where Firefox can access out of the box (user's home is unfortunately not an option)?

Comment: How are you trying to get Firefox to open that file? I'm sure I'm missing something, but I was able to run (for example) `firefox /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-535/html/wayland-issues.html` at a terminal and it worked as expected, so I'm wondering if it's something related to how your app is triggering that action?

Comment: Is your /etc/oqm/static directory listed among the plugs in your snapcraft YAML?

Comment: Interesting, I am using a `xdg-open {file}` command. Actually, it looks like firefox can open files in `/usr/share/doc`. If you want to make an answer saying that files in `/usr/share/doc` are accessible to FF, I'll mark as accepted @johnandmegh .

Comment: @user535733 , My app is not a snap so I do not specify a snapcraft yaml

Answer (score 0):

What you're going for may be easier to accomplish by lining up a bit more with the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard - according to that, [miscellaneous documentation (e.g. not "man pages") should be stored](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s11.html) in `/usr/share/doc`, ideally in a subdirectory. At least on my system, on the Firefox snap version 121.0-1, documentation stored in that location can be opened directly by Firefox - e.g. the following commands work at a terminal:

```
$ firefox /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-535/html/wayland-issues.html
$ xdg-open /usr/share/doc/nvidia-driver-535/html/wayland-issues.html
```

[/etc is more meant to be configuration files](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s07.html), which may be why there are additional "gates" behind the Firefox snap being able to access it - the amount of mischief/malice that could be pulled off by the browser accessing or editing the configuration of core system components (network hosts file, ssh, etc.) would be a pretty tempting target.